# Function declaration with multiple type

Tags: typescript, function, types

I have the following function that takes a String and return a String such as

```
mockingcase('foobar')
// => fOoBaR
```

The project has a Typescript declaration file. I don't know much about Typescript (read nothing other than the last hour spent reading the doc.)

The function `mockingcase` has now the ability to return a String from an Array of string

```
mockingcase(['foo','bar'])
// => 'fOoBaR'
```

How do I change the typescript declaration file so it can take a String or an Array?

original:

```
function mockingcase(input: string, options?: { random?: boolean }): string;
```

my idea:

```
function mockingcase(input: string|array, options?: { random?: boolean }): string;
```

Am I completely wrong?

Comment: `function mockingcase(input: string|string[], options?: { random?: boolean }): string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close - array types must also define what the type of the object *contained* within the array is:

```
input: string | string[]
```

Or:

```
input: string | Array<string>
```